# Devise redirecting to sign in page on invalid attempt with sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using `Devise 3.0.0.`

I am trying to `sign up` with invalid values. After `second invalid attempt` on `sign up`, I am getting a flash message of `'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing'` and it redirects me to `sign in` page instead of `sign up` page.

In my browser its showing on sign up page

```
url: localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

after 1st invalid signup

```
url:- localhost:3000/users
```

after 2nd invalid signup

```
url: localhost:3000/signin
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening?